# POSIX Sockets; Deciphering Hostname from sockaddr_in structure

Tags: sockets, posix

Is it possible to decipher the hostname given the sockaddr_in strucure?

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};

struct in_addr {
    unsigned long s_addr;          // load with inet_pton()
};
```

I'd tried printing out "udp_server.sin_addr.s_addr" (where udp_server is of type struct sockaddr_in) and **it printed me a number.**

I believe the s_addr variable is converted to network long? How do I convert it into a readable format so I can determine the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of functions for transforming the number you mentioned (a network address in long format) to human-readable addresses.

Take a look at `inet_pton()` and `inet_ntop()` (Presentation to Number, Number to Presentation). Those are AF_INET-specific, and work for both IPv4 and IPv6 if I'm not mistaken.

Suerte!

Comment: Note however that this produces human-readable *IP address*, not a *hostname*.  To recover a *hostname*, if all you have is a socket address, you must do a reverse DNS lookup (e.g. using `getnameinfo`) and this is not guaranteed to give you anything useful.  (This is why, for instance, HTTP/1.1 requires the client to tell the server what hostname it thinks it's talking to as application-layer data.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the IP address in network byte order. Use the [`inet_ntoa(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/inet_ntoa.3.html) or [`inet_ntop(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html) to get back a string representation of the IP.